# Crewing vehicles with dead crews

Tags: magic-the-gathering

During the first main phase: I have a 1/2 [Thraben Inspector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThraben%20Inspector%5d) out.  My opponent casts [Harnessed Lightning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHarnessed%20Lightning%5d) targeting the inspector to kill it.  I then tap, in response, the Inspector to crew my [Smuggler's Copter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSmuggler%27s%5d%2b%5bCopter%5d).  Is this legal? Is the Copter crewed and ready to attack in the combat phase?

Comment: The hilarious visual of a bunch of helicopters flying around with dead crews over a city of cars flying through the streets with dead crews has made my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The Crew ability doesn't have any timing restrictions on it, so it can be activated any time you have priority. And once the ability has been activated it doesn't matter what happens to the creature(s) you tapped to activate the ability (even if the Crew ability is still on the stack).

Tapping creatures is a cost of the crew ability. And there is no point between when you have announced the crew ability, when you payed the cost of tapping a creature, and when the ability is put on the stack for your opponent to respond. Once the ability is on the stack removing the crewing creature will not do anything because the cost of activating the ability has already been paid.

From the [Gatherer Rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417808) on the Copter:

> Once a player announces that he or she is activating a crew ability, no player may take other actions until the ability’s been paid for. **Notably, players can’t try to stop the ability by changing a creature’s power or by removing or tapping a creature.**
>
> Creatures that crew a Vehicle aren’t attached to it or related in any other way. Effects that affect the Vehicle, such as by destroying it or giving it a +1/+1 counter, don’t affect the creatures that crewed it **and vice versa**.

Comment: It also works the other way around. If you activate the Copter's ability by tapping the Inspector, destroying the Inspector in response would not prevent the copter from becoming manned.

Comment: Yes, that I understand.  But the question is really, if the crew is killed before I tap it to crew the copter, can I tap the "dead" crew and have the copter crewed?

Comment: @Tony: if you tap them in response, they aren't killed yet, the Harnessed Lightning is still on the stack.

Comment: @Tony Are you really asking 'Can I crew a vehicle in response to a spell?' then?

Comment: Thanks Diego, I guess that is what I was asking.  So basically, the harnessed lightning is on the stack, the tap to crew  goes on top of the lightning, so therefore the vehicle would be crewed.  However if another harnessed lightning would be played on top of the tap to crew, the crew would not make it and the vehicle would be uncrewed right?

Comment: No, that's not right. As ikegami said, destroying the creature that you tapped in response to the crew ability doesn't stop the crew ability from working.

Comment: @Tony Does my edit answer your question better?

Comment: I imagine it may be helpful to explain that the tapping is the cost of activating the ability, and that's why it's too late to do anything by the time it's activated: the cost is already paid, the crewing creature isn't even needed now.

Comment: Yes Diego, got it.  That makes sense to me now.  At FNM some of the players were talking on the side about crewing a vehicle with a "dead crew" now I can clearly see how this works.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the key here is to recognize that crewing a vehicle is just like any other activated ability. A vehicle with "Crew 2" is really just shorthand for "Tap any number of untapped creatures you control with total power 2 or greater: This permanent becomes an artifact creature until end of turn." As with any activated ability, once you pay the cost, it doesn't matter what happens to the land/creatures/etc. you paid with.