# Do enchantments of Crew carry over to Vehicles?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I crew a vehicle with a creature that has an enchantment that does something such as "Whenever enchanted creature attacks, its controller loses 2 life" would that transfer to the vehicle it crews? Also, would enchantments such as a +1/+1 counter move to the vehicle?

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32965/crewing-vehicles-with-dead-crews

Comment: Fun fact: Insolence would trigger in this case. Insolence is an enchantment that reads "whenever enchanted creature becomes tapped, it deals 2 damage to its controller.", so tapping a creature that has an Insolence attached to pay for Crew cost triggers Insolence.

Comment: @steenbergh Also Night Market Lookout, which was designed to work either on its own or when crewing vehicles.

Comment: @Samthere Merfolks are also naturally skilled in driving vehicles.
http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Awhenever+o%3Abecomes+o%3Atapped+t%3A%22creature%22+%28e%3Amt%2Fen+or+e%3Alw%2Fen%29&v=scan&s=issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No to both. Crewing a creature doesn't cause he vehicle to be related to the creatures that crew it in any way unless the creatures have an ability that triggers when they crew a vehicle. Crew means nothing more than what the ability says; that you tap creatures  to make the vehicle into an artifact creature until end of turn.

From the gatherer rulings on [Smuggler's Copter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSmuggler%27s%5d%2b%5bCopter%5d):

> Creatures that crew a Vehicle aren’t attached to it or related in any other way. Effects that affect the Vehicle, such as by destroying it or giving it a +1/+1 counter, don’t affect the creatures that crewed it and vice versa.

Also note that "enchantments such as a +1/+1 counter" makes no sense. A counter is a completely different thing from an enchantment. If you meant an aura enchantment that gives the creature +1/+1, this is unrelated to a +1/+1 counter.

Comment: As a further point, it helps to remember that crewing a vehicle doesn't link the creature and the vehicle in any way (unless later effects get added that reference creatures that crewed a vehicle creature this turn). Abilities can trigger between a crewing creature and a vehicle (e.g. Gearshift Ace), but there's no ongoing link between them. Creatures don't really drive vehicles, but rather turn them on and program them where to go!